# Weigh samples when training an ANN

Tags: matlab, neural-network, weighted

I'm actually training an ANN on MATLAB to optimize a pump. I've got 2000 samples as input of the design of the pump and as an output the efficiency. I've got some good results, but now I want to retrain the model. I want to rearrange the weight per sample such that the samples with better efficiency have a higher weight than the small efficiency.

How can I weigh my samples by efficiency?

Here is a piece of my code:

```
Mdl_NN1 = fitnet([6 4],training);
Mdl_NN1.layers{2}.transferFcn = 'purelin';
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
Mdl_NN1.trainParam.showWindow  = true;
[Mdl_NN1,TR] = train(Mdl_NN1,XtrainSet',YtrainSet(:,2)')
```

The `Xtrainset` is the design of the pump in 6 parameters and the `YtrainSet` is just the efficiency.

Comment: Why did you make that edit? The title should be, well, in the title, there's no need to repeat it in the body. `Xtrainset` is a variable, and thus goes with in-line code formatting, as it currently is. Please do not remove relevant formatting from your posts.

Answer (score 1):

Its all about curating your data (this applies in particular for NNs). So if you want to weight certain samples more than others, duplicate them for training and remove others, which are wrong/false. This is better than fiddling with the weights or changing the portions of train/test/validation.

One word of warning: if you duplicate data, **make sure that it only appears in the training set**. You will get unreliable accuracy if you consider the same examples for training and testing. So you might need to set the training/testing/validation data explicitly. Have a look on [divide data for optimal neural network training](https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ug/divide-data-for-optimal-neural-network-training.html;jsessionid=56ca18f2676d3a0ef7d0955a6c52) in the docs.

```
Mdl_NN1.divideFcn = 'divideind';
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.trainInd = % vector with indices
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.testInd = % vector with indices
Mdl_NN1.divideParam.valInd = % vector with indices
```

or may be sufficient to set if the data is ordered properly

```
Mdl_NN1.divideFcn = 'divideblock';
```